# Facebook API JavaScript SDK Upload Photo and Mention Tag Without Link

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, feed, fb.ui

The situation I am trying to create is:

1. I have a photo I want to upload to Facebook via the page feed.
2. I want to tag someone (who is not a friend) along with the photo.

Right now, I am using the following code which opens another window where I can create my post and tag someone:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: '',
}, function(response){});
```

However, when I try to create the post, it says "href or media is required."

**How can I create a post with a photo without sharing a link, and so that I can still tag people who are not friends?**

Comment: why would you tag people who are not even your friends? that does not make any sense. what is the use case?

Answer (score 0):

To upload a photo, you need to use the `/page-id/photos` endpoint. You have to authorize the user and use the `taggable_friends` endpoint to get friends for tagging. You can´t tag people who are not your friends and you have to let Facebook review your use of `taggable_friends`.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this.just try below code.

```
  FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      display: 'popup',
      picture:'file_Path',
  }, function(response){});
```